# Sort the table by c_criticality field in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

i have one field wonum,C_criticality in workorder.

In C_criticality field have three option

1. critical
2. non-critical
3. tools
   4.null or empty

In that C_criticality field some columns are null(empty) that should come at last.
Now i have to get the output in sorting order by criticality , noncritical ,tool , null value(empty value ) will come.

CREATE TABLE workorder
(
wonum int,
C_criticality varchar(255),
);

INSERT INTO workorder (wonum,C_criticality)
VALUES (2, 'critical');
INSERT INTO workorder (wonum,C_criticality)
VALUES (1, 'non-critical');
INSERT INTO workorder (wonum,C_criticality)
VALUES (15, 'critical');
INSERT INTO workorder (wonum,C_criticality)
VALUES (12, 'tool');
INSERT INTO workorder (wonum,C_criticality)
VALUES (21, 'non-critical');
INSERT INTO workorder (wonum,C_criticality)
VALUES (11, '');

output:-

```
 C_criticality           wonum
   critical                2
   critical                15
  non-critical             21
   tool                    12
   null                   11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try a two-tiered sort using `ISNULL` and `FIELD`:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    ISNULL(C_criticality),   -- 0 for non NULL, 1 for NULL
    FIELD(C_criticality, 'criticality', 'noncritical', 'tool');
```

The call to `FIELD` will order according to the list you provided.

Answer (score 2):

This works for all SQL engines, not just in MySQL

```
select *
from workorder
order by case when C_criticality = 'critical' then 1
              when C_criticality = 'non-critical' then 2
              when C_criticality = 'tools' then 3
              else 4
         end
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have tagged **mysql** the query would be something like ,

```
SELECT * FROM workorder ORDER BY FIELD(C_criticality ,'critical','non-critical','tools','null');
```

Comment: String 'null' is not same as `null`. Your answer is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

It depends from DBMS. In some there are options `NULLS FIRST`, `NULLS LAST`
In MySQL you can find this article interesting https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-order-null-values-first-or-last-in-mysql